# exclude files from list that begin by string in unix

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using s3cmd top copy files to S3 but I want to exclude all files that begin with `00` and are a JPEG.

I'm trying `--exclude=00*.jpg` with no success.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Is that `s3cmd`? Try `--exclude '00*.jpg'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(00*.jpg)
```

Comment: +1, thanks a lot. But it adds some unwanted behaviour. It lists content not  of only the current directory(as ls does by default) but also included directories too.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
for n in $(/bin/ls | grep -v "^00.*.jpg"); do s3cmd $n; done
```